# attachRequestCompleted errors out in init()

Tags: sapui5

I am using following snippet which I am using in init function. My oAppModel is getting loaded with the data. However, oAppModel.attachRequestCompleted() does not get executed even. I have tried to pass oEvent also, but when I use oEvent, it says oEvent is not defined.

```
    var oAppModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
    oAppModel.loadData(oData);
    //attach 
    oAppModel.attachRequestCompleted(function(){
   //get value:
    var soldto = oAppModel.getProperty("/SoldTo/0/Name");

    });
```

Could you please help ?

Answer (score 0):

you are loading data (oData) into the model hence not HTTP(s) request is made. therefore, requestCompleted event is not fired.

it will fire if you do this.
    var oAppModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();